# How to fetch previous 4 records in MySQL based on where condition

Tags: mysql

[image: Sample Data]

I have data in mysql table, i want to fetch last records from given condition.
example: i want to pass month = '11' and year = '2017' and fetch month_id's 11, 10, 9 and 8.

I have added sample data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb01c5/2

Thank you.

Comment: @user2864740 : i tried this, but i'm able to fetch only last record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from `tablename` where year = 2017 AND month<=11 order by month desc  limit 4;
```

or

```
select * from `tablename` where year = 2017 AND month IN (11,10,9,8);
```

Comment: You'll also need the year in the ordering or 2018 could be rough :-)

Answer (score 2):

The SQL could be written something like so:

```
select *
from d
-- find all rows for this month or previous
where
   (year = 2017) and (month <= 11)  -- same month / earlier in same year
or (year < 2017)                    -- earlier year
-- for all found rows, order descending by year, then month
order by year desc, date desc
-- take the first 4 (descending by date)
limit 4
```

It would be simpler if the year+month were stored as a compound value - eg. the first of the month - but the same logic would apply to find the "n records before".

Answer (score 1):

check for this   `select * from mt_month where month_id<=11 order by month_id desc  limit 4`

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the month you want the data from, why not use `select * from mt_month
where start_date BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-11-01'` to return your data? Rather thank pass the month_id you can pass the start date and end date for your between query

Comment: requirement was like that. we have only month and year from frontend.

Comment: This is not generic and scalable. Will you always want to return 4 records all the time? Will each month always have 1 record? What will happen if month 11 has 5 records? These are some of the considerations you need to make

Comment: Yes we are developing report which should show  current month and previous 3months data..  So needed.

Comment: The best thing is to get the previous 3 months dates using the passed date from the front end and then use those in your between clause...that's what i would do

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this example:

```
select * from mt_month
 where year=2017 AND month=11
 order By year Desc limit 4;
```